# problem in flv video streaming in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, video-streaming, flv, flowplayer

i'm using flowPlayer inside a user control in sharepoint 2010

this user control works well when testing it in normal web page

but when i put it in a web part in a sharepoint project

the player appears blank and movie doesn't work

** this problem may be casued by IIS7

any ideas please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there were no problems at all :D

i just forget to put the correct link of the .swf playe file